# how to handle push notification by the kind of notification

Tags: iphone

i want to handle the notification, in my app i have 2 tabs(friends,jobs) with navigation controller,and a barbutton on each navigation controller named 'notification'(on click it displays tableview).
On notification, if its job related it shud open the page linked to barbutton on jobs tab and if it is friends related it shud open the page linked to barbutton on friends tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notification contains a userInfo dictionary. The contents of this is set by the push provider. So assuming that you're also the provider of pushes to your app, you can just add a key to the userInfo dictionary that your app will read when the push arrives.